# MySQL - fetching data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have this structure of tables:
**menu**

```
id | name
1  | Electronics
2  | Cars
3  | Bikes
4  | Music
```

**products**

```
id | brand_name | product_name | price | description | ...
1  | Lenovo     | Notebook ABC | 800   | ...         | ...
2  | Apple      | iPad Mini    | 400   | ...         | ...
3  | Bonton     | Taylor Swift | 15    | ...         | ...
4  | BMW        | BMW 3 2010   | 30000 | ...         | ...
```

**categories**

```
id_product | id_menu
1          | 1
1          | 7
1          | 9
4          | 2
3          | 10
```

And I am trying to print out for every brand all its categories and from each category to print out 10 products order by the highest price, so the output would look like this:

```
Apple - Electronics - iPad Mini - 400
Apple - Electronics - iPad 2 - 300
Apple - Electronics - iPad - 180
Bonton - Music - Taylor Swift - 15
Bonton - Music - U2 - 13
...
```

The lack of the table with all brands makes my life tougher, so I'll probably add it to the scheme. But could I ask you guys for helping me with a query, that would fetch the information as I outlined?

Thank you very much, it looks too much for me right now.

**EDIT:**

As I use PHP, I think that it can be also in 2 queries (I am unable to do it with one query, but struggling also with 2 MySQL queries in PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set @num := 0, @brand := '';
```

`SELECT p.brand, m.name,p.name, p.price,
    @num := if(@brand = p.brand, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
    @brand := p.brand AS dummy
    FROM category c 
    INNER JOIN products p 
    ON p.id = c.id_product 
    INNER JOIN menu m ON m.id = c.id_menu
    GROUP BY p.brand, p.price, p.name
    HAVING row_number < 10
    ORDER BY p.price DESC;`

Not sure it this do exactly what you are expecting. Hope it helps.

Comment: You don't limit to 10 rows per brand.

Comment: Thank you @ppolak, I'll try it. But speaking about choosing those 10 products with higher price, where to put this limitation?

Comment: @user2932090  found nice article http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/